# Quantity update not working for second product AJAX PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to add products with AJAX into the cart from the products page with the quantity field. the addition of the first item is working fine with desired quantity but when I try to add a second product with a different quantity it keeps sending the first product quantity into the database.

here is my code

HTML

```
<div class="pro-quantity">
 <div class="quantity">
  <button class="decrement-btn">-</button>
  <input type="text" id="sqty" maxlength="2" max="10" value="1" class="qty-input">
  <button class="increment-btn">+</button>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="pro-id-2">
<div class="tw-flex tw-justify-between tw-items-center">
                                                        
<button class="pro-id-link" value="<? echo $id; ?>" id="add-deposit">Add to Cart</button>
<input type="hidden" name="" id="cus_id" value="<? echo $_SESSION['u_id']; ?>">
</div>
</div>
```

JS (for increment and decrement quantity)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.increment-btn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var incre_value = $(this).parents('.quantity').find('.qty-input').val();
    var value = parseInt(incre_value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    if (value < 10) {
      value++;
      $(this).parents('.quantity').find('.qty-input').val(value);
    }

  });

  $('.decrement-btn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var decre_value = $(this).parents('.quantity').find('.qty-input').val();
    var value = parseInt(decre_value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    if (value > 1) {
      value--;
      $(this).parents('.quantity').find('.qty-input').val(value);
    }
  });

});
```

JS (AJAX code)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(document).on("click", "#add-deposit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var element = $(this);
    var id = $(this).val();
    var cus_id = $('#cus_id').val();
    var sqty = $('#sqty').val();

    $.ajax({
      url: "add_deposit_script.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        id: id,
        cus_id: cus_id,
        sqty: sqty
      },
      success: function (data) {
        if (data === 'success') {
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: 'Success.',
            text: 'Success! This product has been added into Deposit.'
          })
        }
        if (data === 'error') {
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Error.',
            text: 'Error! This Product is already in your deposit.'
          })
        }
        element.prop('disabled', true);
        element.html('Added');
        getcartnumber();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: There are issues with the code you have posted above. `class="qty-inpu">` ~ missing `t` - possibly others too

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius sorry it was a typo in question.

Comment: Is this HTML code generated in loop, so there are multiple elements with `id="add-deposit"`?

Comment: What causes the `$id` to change - you have that assigned to the button? Is it, as suggested by @Robert, in a loop of some sort?

Comment: @Robert yes HTML code is in the PHP while loop

Comment: ID attributes **must** be unique! Javascript functions that rely upon IDs will yield incorrect results as a result of duplicate IDs - commonly the effect that you are seeing. Use other forms of selectors to identify and process DOM elements (ie: dataset attributes, sibling/parent/child type selectors ) etc

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius can you please write a piece of code for solution? I am new to jquery

Comment: I don't use jQuery myself - so anything I did write would not be optimal by any means.